# Navigation drawer with navigation drawer fragment

Tags: android, android-navigation

i am new in android development. Not able to understand navigation drawer activity. I am building the project in eclipse luna targeting api 19 and this activity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.

I am not able to find any link about this topic.

Comment: Request to use google for tutorial search and do not post question here for tutorial link. Anyway for android tutorial the best site is developer.android.com. And start using android studio IDE   answer to question https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: there are lots and lots of links. please use tutorials or blogs to find what you are looking for rather than just posting it here.

Comment: i couldn't find your comments useful. Anyway thanks for commenting. I googled but couldn't find anything helpful. That is why i questioned here.

Answer (score 0):

i will recommend you to use Android Studio. Eclipse ADT now has no support from Google.
Recently i did this. And im satisfied

What is for about NavigationView it is now included in support library from Google.

it is rather simple to use. In xml use NavigationView inside DrawerLayout. Java code will be less difficult. Google is your helper for further questions ;)